# Is there a way to intelligently remove rows of zeros to get a square matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

In linear algebra, the [Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is a scalar value that can be computed from the elements of a square matrix and encodes certain properties of the linear transformation described by the matrix.

To compute the determinant, some rows or columns of matrices need to be cut.

for instance, the matrix A

```
A = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[0,0]])
A
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```

needs to cut the last row

```
B = A[:2]
B
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

then, determinant operation is available.

```
np.linalg.det(B)
0.0
```

what another matrix needs to be cut is column rather than row

```
C = A.T
C
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

so, cutting a row or column is not determined, is there a way to intelligently remove rows of zeros to get a square matrix in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove rows or columns that are all zero (i.e. select rows or columns with any non-zero value), you can use the following.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
               [0, 0],
               [4, 5]])
B_rows = A[(A != 0).any(1), :]  # Remove rows that are all zero.
>>> B_rows
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])

A = np.array([[1, 2, 0],
               [3, 4, 0]])
B_cols = A[:, (A != 0).any(0)]  # Remove columns that are all zero.
>>> B_cols
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You should use [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
A = np.delete(A,2,1)
```

The first parameter is the numpy array that needs to be cut. The second parameter you put the index of the column you want to cut. The last parameter is the axis, you put 0 there if you want to delete a row (like you managed to do in your example), but 1 if you want to delete a column.